# How is dynamically created array in jquery is accessed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have created a script that adds items on click into an array.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var array_ids = [];
        $('.add').click(function()
        {
            array_ids.push($(this).parent().siblings('.row_id').html().trim());
            alert(array_ids);    
        });
    });
```

Items are coming from mysql database so I am storing primary keys of items. keys are stored in array like this manner

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Now I want to access this array in php so that I could store in database one by one.

I thought to doing some ajax and this is my code

```
$('.show').click(function(e)
        {
            //e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax(
            {
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'createsale.php',
               data: {items: array_ids},
               success: function()
               {
                    alert('done'); 
               } 
            });
        });
```

I get the done alert but couldn't manage to get it stored in database. Can anyone tell how do I insert those items in mysql?

Comment: where is `createsale.php` ?

Comment: I couldn't think of how to get the sent array!  I though  $result = $array_id; would work but nope.

Comment: Data sent to php through GET/POST are stored in the super globals `$_GET` and `$_POST`

Comment: Do you already have the query / rows where the IDs are stored?

Comment: Yess! And When ever I click add an id gets stored in array! I do not know to access the array now

Comment: You have to change the way you're handling the IDs.. on your loop, $array_id[] = $row; then you must return json_encode($array_id);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121432/cannot-access-array-from-jquery

Comment: I did some changed but guide me now please

Answer (score 1):

Send the value from Javascript by using **Json** `{"key":value}` or array `[1,2,3]`. While getting them to use them in PHP, you can use `json_decode()` to convert the Json or array from Javascript to PHP.

If you want your information from PHP to Javascript, Just use the funtion `json_encode()` that will send a **json** string.

Ref: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121432/cannot-access-array-from-jquery  please see this question

Comment: This answer is correct, json_encode, json_decode are the methods for deal with array/Jason data to and from php into JavaScript/HTML

Answer (score 0):

your `createsale.php` file should has something like this below code to receive array Data & dont forget to escape your data using `mysql_real_escape_string` before doing any mysql query

```
    <?php
          if(isset($_POST["items"]) && $_POST["items"] !=""){
            $arr = $_POST["items"];
            //convert JS array to PHP array
            $arr = json_decode($arr,true);
            //then you have your PHP array => new array(1,2,3,...);

            /*  use for/forEach loop
         for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
            do the task
         }
            */
        }
   ?>
```