# Cannot access array from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay prior to my previous question I have tried a bit of modification to my code but somehow I am still lagging.

This is jquery I have created

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var array_ids = [];
        $('.add').click(function()
        {
            array_ids.push($(this).parent().siblings('.row_id').html().trim());
            alert(array_ids);    
        });

        $('.show').click(function(e)
        {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array_ids);
            $.ajax(
            {
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'addsale.php',
               data: {data : jsonString},
               cache: false,
               dataType: "json",
               success: function()
               {
                 console.log(data.reply);
                alert(data.reply);
               } 
            });
        });
    });
```

And addsale.php

```
if(isset($_POST['push'])) //tried it commenting also!
{
$data = array();
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
foreach($data as $d){
 echo $d;
 }
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing to access the array and get the html from addsale.php to current page?

Comment: Use `$_POST['data']`

Comment: $data = $_POST['data'];  this thing ??

Comment: Your `$.ajax()` success callback uses a variable `data` that isn't defined (you probably want it declared as `success: function(data) { ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var array_ids = [];
    $('.add').click(function()
    {
        array_ids.push($(this).parent().siblings('.row_id').html().trim());
        alert(array_ids);    
    });

    $('.show').click(function(e)
    {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //prefer parse function
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array_ids);
        $.ajax(
        {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'addsale.php',
           data: {"data" : jsonString},
           cache: false,
           dataType: "json",
           //e is the response text from your PHP code
           success: function(e)
           {
             //I don't know why this code
             //console.log(data.reply);
            //alert(data.reply);
           } 
        });
    });
});
```

in your PHP code try

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) //tried it commenting also!
{
   $data = array();
   $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
   foreach($data as $d){
       echo $d;
   }
 }
```

Comment: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Whenever I click add it saves like this 1 then again click 1,2 then again click 1,2,3

Comment: It's ok `stringify()` for array to Json. In case you want Json `{"key":"value"}` you can use `parse()`. It's preferable using json for your comunication from PHP to Javascript or vice et versa.

Answer (score 0):

echo with `foreach` will not good handling for json response ! You should loop that json after response to ajax `success` function ...

**addsale.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) //tried it commenting also!
{
   $data = array();
   $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
   echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

**access json resposne in ajax**

```
$.ajax(
        {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'addsale.php',
           data: {"data" : jsonString},
           cache: false,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(d)
           {
             //I don't know why this code
             console.log(d);
           } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have everything correct but missing something right `data: {data: ... }`, you should also add something like below-

```
 data : {data : jsonString, 'push':'push'},
```

and in php code you try to decode the an array which is not in json format,
your code just need to be like this-

```
  if(isset($_POST['push'])) //tried it commenting also!
  {
      foreach($_POST['data'] as $d){
         echo $d;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No `data` argument in your success function. Modify your addsale.php

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var array_ids = [];
    $('.add').click(function()
    {
        array_ids.push($(this).parent().siblings('.row_id').html().trim());
        alert(array_ids);    
    });
    $('.show').click(function(e)
    {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array_ids);
        $.ajax(
        {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'addsale.php',
           data: {data : jsonString},
           cache: false,
           dataType: "json",
           success:function(data)
           {
             console.log(data.reply);
             alert(data.reply);
           } 
        });
    });
});
```

addsale.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) //tried it commenting also!
{
$data=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
echo json_encode(['reply'=>$data]);
exit();
}
```